# C++ Assignment don't work

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

Sorry for this very simple looking problem, but I have no idea what causes it:

In a C++ project I have a loop in a loop in a loop and have to leave the inner two so I have a variable for a query. In the first iteration it works fine, but in the second the assign from dtime to abbruch does not work. In the Debugger dtime has correctly the value "1" and abbruch "0" but this stays after the assignment. Both are of type long.

```
for (sect = 0; sect <= sections; sect++)
{
    abbruch = 0;
    for(line = 0; line < maxlines ; line ++)
    {
        abbruch = dtime[sect][0];
        if(abbruch != 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        for (index = 0; index < 30; index ++)
        {
            if (complicated query)
            {
                dtime[sect][0] = DiffTime[maxlines * sect + line];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use VS2012 Ultimate. 
Has anyone an idear how this can happen ot how to solve it?

Comment: If you are debugging a release build this kind of apparent error is merely the fault of the debugger. Use a debug build when you want to examine variables after a breakpoint or single-step.

Answer (score 0):

`break` will only take you out of the current `for` loop. In your case, the loop over `index` will not be called following a `break` when `abbruch != 0` as that `break` will take you out of the loop over `line`. The other `break` statement will take you out of the loop over `index`.

That's the rationale, but, by far the best thing to do is to step through with a debugger. I wouldn't use break statements in this way as it's too confusing. Consider breaking the triple loop structure into function calls using `return` statements in place of `break`s.

Also, it's a good idea to localise the interating variables in the for loops, e.g.

```
for (int sect = 0; sect <= sections; sect++)
```

Comment: Yes thats intended. In fact I want to break only when dtime gets a value != 0 in the index loop, so it should break in the next itteration of the line loop with the if(abbruch != 0) querry.

Comment: What's the data type of abbruch? abbruch != 0 is not good if it's a floating point.

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe mean to put this?

```
abbruch = dtime[sect][line];
```

(line instead of 0)

But also what Bathseba said is true. A break will only break one for-loop.

Comment: In this step it is only neccessary to get the first line for each section.
Because the break statement only breaks one loop I have the second one in the (abbruch != 0) querry.